# Display link dock does not work in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displaylink

I bought the HP travel dock that has Display Link and it does not display video when connecting the HDMI cable.

Here are some infos:

lsusb output:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 17e9:4352 DisplayLink 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 03f0:a11d HP, Inc 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 174f:116a Syntek EasyCamera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e500 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 048d:1165 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. IT1165 Flash Controller
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 03f0:0355 HP, Inc 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Info:

```
System:    Kernel: 5.17.3-051703-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: Gnome 3.36.9 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 80YH v: Lenovo ideapad 320-15IKB serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: LENOVO model: Cairo 5A v: SDK0J40688 WIN serial: <filter> UEFI [Legacy]: LENOVO v: 4WCN26WW date: 05/26/2017 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i7-7500U bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Amber Lake rev: 9 L2 cache: 4096 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 bogomips: 23199 
           Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 400/3500 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1187 2: 1200 3: 1187 4: 1200 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 620 vendor: Lenovo driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 940MX] vendor: Lenovo driver: nouveau v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: modesetting,nouveau,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,vesa tty: N/A 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.6 direct render: Yes 

Info:      Processes: 251 Uptime: 23m Memory: 11.48 GiB used: 2.61 GiB (22.7%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.4.0 
           Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38
```